# Why an element doesn't move up in FF but does in Chrome? How to solve it in FF?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I experience a strange behavior in FF: an element doesn't allow to move up the other element. Everything works fine in Chrome but doesn't work in FF.

[image]

Please see Jsfiddle in FF http://jsfiddle.net/M74F9/4/.

To see what is the issue please find in a console a `<div class="layout-content">` element. And try to set its `margin-top` to negative value say `-50px`. Set the value with arrows, it will let you see the movement of the `div`. The `div` moves up but the word "Account" stops and doesn't want to move with the `div`. It seems that the `nav` element of the Bootstrap doesn't allow to move it.

Why it happens? What styles stop an "Account" word? Why it happens only in FF and doesn't happen in Chrome? How to solve it in FF?

Comment: Did you check with     position:absolute?

Comment: It looks exactly the same in both browsers to me. What versions are you using?

Comment: @Marcel, Chrome: 36.0.1985.125 m, FF: 31.0.

Comment: I am using chrome 36 and FF 30 and they look identical.